# How to label-encoded different shaped list data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

My pandas series looks like this, and I want to use LabelEncoder but got this error

```sh
unhashable type: 'list'
```

```
6           [1]
7          [14]
8           [1]
9           [6]
10      [2, 14]
11          [2]
12         [14]
```

I've tried convert list to string, but items' shape in list are not the same. Here's my code.

```py
df_ln['LN_USES'] = df_ln.groupby('CUST_NO')['LN_USE'].transform('unique')
df_ln['LN_USES'] = df_ln['LN_USES'].apply(np.ndarray.tolist)
encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit_transform(df_ln['LN_USES'])
```

The result I wanted:

```
6           1
7           2
8           1
9           3
10          4
11          5
12          2
```

Comment: Can you make a tuple out of the list? Tuples are immutable and might work for you

Comment: @G.Anderson Thanks, it works. I've tried tuple before. But my code was wrong, here's the correct one: df['LN_USES'] = tuple(map(tuple, df['LN_USES']))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to concatenate all the elements in the list with a separator and turn it into a string. Then apply the encoder.

```
df_ln['LN_USES'] = df_ln['LN_USE'].apply(lambda x: '_'.join(map(str, x)))

#    CUST_NO   LN_USE LN_USES
# 0        6      [1]       1
# 1        7     [14]      14
# 2        8      [1]       1
# 3        9      [6]       6
# 4       10  [2, 14]    2_14
# 5       11      [2]       2
# 6       12     [14]      14


encoder.fit_transform(df_ln['LN_USES'])
# array([0, 1, 0, 4, 3, 2, 1], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: I found the problem is that LN_USE values looks like this 01,06,01,14
so it will transform to 0_1, 0_6, 0_1, 1_4, is there another way to avoid 0 and two digit been split?

Comment: So your `LN_USE` column has entries like `[01, 06, 01, 14]`?

Comment: I'm apologize for my misleading. It's more like [01], [06], [01], [14] the same as your answer above. But somehow I didn't get your output. Is it possible np.ndarray type problem.

Comment: I guess you could first cast your list items to int like this: `df_ln['LN_USE'].apply(lambda x: '_'.join(map(str, map(int, x))))`